# added wrong path to .bash_profile now I can not found any command

Tags: bash, unix, path

I was trying to add conda into my path. But after I added

```
export PATH="/data1/neyozhyang/anaconda3/bin/conda"
```

to my `.bash_profile` I can not use most of the commands like `ls` anymore.

It is a linux server.

`echo $PATH` gives me  `/data1/neyozhyang/anaconda3/bin/conda`
while `echo $HOME` gives me `/data1/neyozhyang`

Comment: You overwrote your `PATH` while you should have just appended to it, e.g. `PATH=/data1/neyozhyang/anaconda3/bin/conda:$PATH` (the old path plus the conda directory)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose an editor by it's full path and open ~/.bash_profile.

```
$ /usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile
$ /usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
$ /usr/bin/emacs ~/.bash_profile
```

And modify the PATH line:

```
export PATH="/data1/neyozhyang/anaconda3/bin/conda:$PATH"
```

Comment: Also, get rid of the quotes. They're unnecessary and WILL cause problems if $PATH has special characters.

Comment: @Gordon They're redundant, but how can they cause problems?

Comment: There's a [unix.se] question where someone screwed up by using single quotes, but double quotes should be safe.

Comment: @sergiotaxz '''/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile''' gives me an empty file now

Comment: Maybe only a bug in older bash versions, but escaped spaces and other characters don't (or at least didn't) parse correctly if $PATH is quoted.

Comment: @NeyoYang what .bash_profile have you edited then if you have not any .bash_profile in your home. May ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile?

Comment: @sergiotarxz I edited both ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile. However, I am able to recover my path by setting '''PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin'''

Comment: @Gordon Do you have a link for this? Quote on the right-hand side of an assignment don't have any effect at all.

Comment: @Gordon Did you double-quote a space with something like `PATH="/foo\ bar/:$PATH"`? In that case, yes, the backslash would be treated literally rather than quoting the space as you intended. Either `PATH=/foo\ bar:$PATH` or `PATH="/foo bar:$PATH"` would have been sufficient.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to quote the RHS of a variable assignment: word splitting and pathname expansion are specifically NOT performed -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get back on your feet (although you don't specify your OS)

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

That gives you something like `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` so you should be able to access the base utilities.

Comment: Cool, but I've tried it and it doesn't return /usr/local/bin, /usr/games and other paths in the Debian GNU/Linux system.